# phonegap platform add ios - "Unexpected token =>" error

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, phonegap-cli

I have a Phonegap app and need to build it in a Mac. Everything works in a machine and I'm trying to configure a new one, but on this, when I run **phonegap platform add ios** I receive the following error:

```
$ phonegap platform add ios
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/util/connect-proxy.js:21
                fs.readFile(settings, (err, data) => {
                                                  ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/serve.js:9:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Both Macs are running with node v0.12.7 and npm 2.11.3.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `phonegap` is using *ECMAScript 6 Features* like [Arrow Functions](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#arrows). 
I think this is resulting into your error, because you are still using `Node v0.12.7`, which does not support these features. Installing the latest LTS version from [Official Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) should fixed that.

For further information please have a look at the [phonegap requirements](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli).

Answer (score 0):

Please update your node and npm version to solved your problem.